# Why am I getting permission denied on my Travis CI build for rebar?

Tags: erlang, bitbucket, travis-ci, nitrogen

I ran a build, on Travis CI and got a permission denied error:

> $ source ${TRAVIS_HOME}/otp/23.0/activate
> 3.01s$ ./rebar get-deps /home/travis/.travis/functions: line 355: ./rebar: Permission denied The command "eval ./rebar get-deps "
> failed. Retrying, 2 of 3. /home/travis/.travis/functions: line 355:
> ./rebar: Permission denied The command "eval ./rebar get-deps "
> failed. Retrying, 3 of 3. /home/travis/.travis/functions: line 355:
> ./rebar: Permission denied The command "eval ./rebar get-deps " failed
> 3 times. The command "./rebar get-deps" failed and exited with 126
> during . Your build has been stopped.

I don't understand why I am getting this error message. I used the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen/blob/master/.travis.yml) from the nitrogen framework which my project uses as a base. As you can see my [.travis.yml](https://bitbucket.org/ookma-kyi/ookma-kyi-core/src/master/.travis.yml) is the same. Can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seem the OS path write permission problem. It is related to  `eval ./rebar get-deps` failed. You can debug the problem by running `./rebar get-deps` by yourself and find which path the program want to use, then set the path permission correctly or may be the path already exists.

Or `rm -Rf deps` may be helpful.

It may be related to `rebar` application, use `chmod 700 rebar` to solve the problem.

The followings are .travis.yml and Makefile, it show it use local `./rebar` file. you can change Makefile to global `rebar` file.

> nitrogen/.travis.yml
>
> language: erlang script: "make travis" otp_release:
>
> - 23.0
> - 22.0
> - 21.3 before_script: "sudo apt-get --yes --force-yes install libpam-runtime"

> nitrogen/Makefile
>
> REBAR:=./rebar
>
> get-deps:     $(REBAR) get-deps
>
> update-deps:  $(REBAR) update-deps
>
> compile:  $(REBAR) compile

I think you can branch your own `nitrgeon` repository, and use it then you can edit code as you like.

In addition, `nitregon` try to run the download program(rebar), your `travis` think this action is dangerous for running uncontrollable code as it will crash your server as virus.

Test the `travis.ci` in your pc then test it into production system.

Comment: I can't, it's not a system I can actually log on to. It is Travis CI, a continuous build system and all builds are done in a bubble of sorts. Sorry if my explanation is difficult to understand. I am new to all of this.

Comment: I think it use local `rebar` program in the nitrogen source code, but `rebar` is not executable. So you can search `rebar` application and find it and `chmod 700 rebar`.

Comment: Chen Yu: this is for a Travis CI build not an actual physical or virtual system, so I can't actually log in to issue that command unless I'm supposed to put it in my .travis.yml file itself.

Comment: edit the reply as above